# Parsing response from a HTTP web service (JSON) in PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services, http

I need to consume a HTTP Web Service whose response in JSON format. How can i achieve this in php given the URL of the web service is known ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
$data = file_get_contents(<url of that website>);
$data = json_decode($data, true); // Turns it into an array, change the last argument to false to make it an object
```

This should be able to turn the JSON data into an array.

Now, to explain what it does.

`file_get_contents()` essentially gets the contents of a file, either remote or local. This is through the HTTP portal, so you are not violating the privacy policy by using this function for remote content.

Then, when you use `json_decode()`, it normally changes JSON text to an object in PHP, but since we added `true` for the second argument, it returns an associative array instead.

Then you can do anything with the array.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

you need to `json_decode()` the response and then you have it as a php array to process it

Answer (score 2):

First read the responce using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html). And then, use json_decode() to parse the response you got using curl.

Answer (score 2):

```
    // setup curl options
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://serviceurl.com/api',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );

    // perform request
    $cUrl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array( $cUrl, $options );
    $response = curl_exec( $cUrl );
    curl_close( $cUrl );

    // decode the response into an array
    $decoded = json_decode( $response, true );
```